# Chrome нашёл лишнюю скобку там, где её нет

Tags: google-chrome

Во время проверки полностью работоспособной страницы с js(проверял по консоли), Chrome нашёл лишнюю закрывающую фигурную скобку в... meta charset. И из-за этого теперь ничего не работает. Подскажите, что делать?[image: ...]

По просьбам:
1)До meta charset идёт только `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.
2)Вызов js файла убран, а ошибка осталась.

Всё стало ещё хуже. Теперь ошибка находится ВСЕГДА во второй строке, чего бы там ни было.[image: !!!]

Comment: Может, перед `<meta charset>` скрипт включен, и в нем лишняя закрывающая скобка?

Comment: Добавьте информации, что было до тега <meta>

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос всё что вне `body`, а так же напишите имя файла, есть подозрение что он ,js

Comment: хром известен тем, что иногда исправляет мелкие ошибки. Рекомендую скачать данную страницу curl'ом или wget'ом и посмотреть по факту содержимое файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался прост: дело в том, что на странице вызывался сторонний код с помощью AJAX, и там была кнопка, у которой в действии было получение значения одного поля ввода- проблема решилась перемещением функции из вызываемого файла в вызывающий.

Answer (score 1):

Можете не смотреть в верхнию часть документа и искать проблему. По опыту скажу, что у вас ошибка в js коде, который в теле документа. Если у вас кода не много, проблем с поиском не должно возникнуть. Можно ставить брейкпоинты в дебаггере, а можно и вырезать код. Это не единственный косяк у chrome. Бывает, что он не отображает js код в теле документа и приходится перезагружать страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Ты каким-то образом подсовываешь html-страницу в качестве js.

Стоит проверить адреса подключаемых скриптов и отсутствие ajax-запросов, явно ожидающих js, либо получающих текущую страницу с content-type text/javascript или application/javascript.